# How can I plot with transparent lines using gnuplot automatically?

Tags: gnuplot

How can I plot with transparent lines using gnuplot automatically?

I plot a histogram with `col=adjustcolor(i,alpha.f=0.2)` as following in R automatically.
I want to do same thing in gnuplot.

```
hist(rnorm(1000,mean=2),col=adjustcolor(1,alpha.f=0.2),xlim=c(0,10))
for(i in 2:3){
  hist(rnorm(1000,mean=2*i),col=adjustcolor(i,alpha.f=0.2),add=T)
}
legend("topleft",legend=c(1,2,3),col=1:3,lty=1)
```

[histogram plot in R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QSwV.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want the histogram to have some transparency? That can be accomplished by using `set style fill`:

```
set term png
set out "test.png"

set style fill transparent solid 0.50 border
plot "-" w boxes lc "blue"
1 10
2 12
3 15
4 17
5 15
6 12
7 10
8 08
9 06
```

Also, if you want the actual line to be transparent, just modify the `lc` argument:

```
plot "-" w boxes lc rgb "#80EE6363"
```

where the first two digits after the `#` are the transparency, and the next 6 characters are the RGB code for the color you want. Hope it helps!